# Remove "Add To Card" only Home page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, storefront

I want to remove "Add To Card" or any other button on home page of WooCommerce Theme but not from product single page.

For example:
Home Page: https://demo.woothemes.com/storefront/
Product Single Page: https://demo.woothemes.com/storefront/product/build-your-dslr/

I don't want to show any button on home page under product. [image: Home Page]

But I want to show button on product page. [image]

I want to do this because i want to force my website visitor to visit product single page.

Which code line will I remove from website > Appearance > Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_loop_add_to_cart_on_home', 1 );
function remove_loop_add_to_cart_on_home() {
    if( is_front_page() ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

---

To remove it on shop page too you will have:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_loop_add_to_cart_on_home', 1 );
function remove_loop_add_to_cart_on_home() {
    if( is_front_page() || is_shop() ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

See [Woocommerce conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

Comment: Thanks its working on home page. What I do? to remove it from "shop page"(www.mywebsite.com/shop).

Comment: Again thanks, help me again that what I do? to remove it from Related Products section. http://prntscr.com/j7d05u

Comment: @awais This is different and much more complicated… You will have to ask a new question for that.