# WooCommerce: Remove add to cart buttons on archives but not in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, cart

I want to remove the "Add to cart" Button on every page except the cart itself.

I found a solution to remove the cart button with an hook:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
```

Works fine but that removes the button everywhere.

I tried this code to remove the button everywhere but the cart:

```
if (!is_cart()) :
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
endif;
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Is there any other way without touching a template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do the trick (based on [`woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.0/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1230-L1271) original function code):

```
add_action('init', 'remove_add_to_cart_function_callback' );
function remove_add_to_cart_function_callback() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' ) ) {

    function custom_template_loop_add_to_cart( $args = array() ) {
        global $product;

        if ( $product && is_cart() ) {
            $defaults = array(
                'quantity'   => 1,
                'class'      => implode(
                    ' ',
                    array_filter(
                        array(
                            'button',
                            'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
                            $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
                            $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'attributes' => array(
                    'data-product_id'  => $product->get_id(),
                    'data-product_sku' => $product->get_sku(),
                    'aria-label'       => $product->add_to_cart_description(),
                    'rel'              => 'nofollow',
                ),
            );

            $args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults ), $product );

            if ( isset( $args['attributes']['aria-label'] ) ) {
                $args['attributes']['aria-label'] = wp_strip_all_tags( $args['attributes']['aria-label'] );
            }

            wc_get_template( 'loop/add-to-cart.php', $args );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Remove "Add To Card" only Home page in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49908652/remove-add-to-card-only-home-page-in-woocommerce/49908992#49908992)

Comment: wow, that's a lot of code for that function! But it works, thank you! ;-)

Comment: Just copied original [`woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart.html#1207-1245) function code adding in it `is_cart()`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try if isn't cart?

```
if (!is_cart()) :
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
endif;
```

Comment: yes, sorry. That was a typo from me. But that's not working either.